# sku is not taking more than 64 charactars

Tags: sku

we are uploading a sku i.e having more than 64 charactars.

but if we enter the sku with more than 64 charactars, its not taking in the backend

I want to increase the value to more than 64 cahractars.

please help me to find solution

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply alter column sku's varchar value from 64 to something you need.

```
ALTER TABLE  `catalog_product_entity` CHANGE  `sku`  `sku` VARCHAR( 500 )
```

Answer (score 0):

there is option to make increase size from below file. Will override this file
app/code/local/Mage/Catalog/Model/Product/Attribute/Backend/Sku.php
Change const SKU_MAX_LENGTH = 64; to const SKU_MAX_LENGTH = 255;

Comment: Please don't edit the core. This way patches and updates can't be applied to the shop

Comment: please check updated answer....